# adding child on canvas and set it "on-top" when clicking the mouse

Tags: apache-flex

I need to add an UIComponent (Label for example) as a child on a canvas and I need to set it on-top (when user click on the label with the mouse, the target event will be the label and not the canvas)
I'm sure flash has a solution for that but I can't find it on the net.
any help?
Best regards.
elad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what "Set it on top" means.

If you want a Label to respond to mouse events, you may have to set the [buttomMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode) property to true.

If you want to swap the Z-Order of different components in your canvas, you can use the [swapChildren](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren%28%29) or [swapChildrenAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildrenAt%28%29) methods.

If you want to the label to somehow become the parent of the canvas, and the canvas a child of the label, you have a long and difficult road ahead of you.

Comment: @Boyd it really depends what the original poster means by "set it on top".